# Is the on screen Enterprise turbolift synchronized to its real location in the ship?

Tags: star-trek

I vaguely remember a video showing this. It was done split screen with one side being a scene from TOS depticting Kirk and Spock having a conversation in a turbolift on their way to the bridge. The other side was a schematic of the Enterprise with a dot running along where the location of the turbolift would be.

The video shows that the lights in the turbolift change directions as they would if it was really moving through the ship. It was meant to show the level of detail that Gene Roddenberry put into the show.

Since I can't find the video I am unsure of the authenticity. Was this actually a consideration during production?

Comment: It certainly does in the Motion Picture; Note the little glowing dot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/W9CYm.gif

Comment: Pretty sure the video you are referring to is the Plinkett Review of one of the Star Trek movies, possibly the Abrams reboot. He compares how they can have conversations in the turbo lift and tracks them thru the blueprints versus in the new movie when the lofts are now nigh instantaneous.

Comment: I know the video you're talking about; it was definitely about the turbolift usage in TOS and how the apparent speed didn't match up with the amount of time spent in the Turbolift.

Comment: We do see the turbolift depicted on a display in the turbolift in TMP that appears to update in realtime. The same display also appears in ST:II, likely due to set reuse.  A similar animated display is visible in ST:IX.  DS9 4x22 in the Defiant turbolift, but is not animated.ST:V.